# Rewrite part of URL with a specific query string to different domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, query-string, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a set of url's to a different domain only when a specific query string is set. Only the main domain url needs to be rewritten, the rest of the url path needs to stay the same and the query string needs to be removed too.

Examples:

```
http://www.domain-a.com/post-type-a/post-title/?template=custom
```

should redirect to:

```
http://www.domain-b.com/post-type-a/post-title/
```

and

```
http://www.domain-a.com/post-type-b/post-title/?template=custom
```

should redirect to:

```
http://www.domain-b.com/post-type-b/post-title/
```

and

```
http://www.domain-a.com/post-type-c/post-title/?template=custom
```

should redirect to:

```
http://www.domain-b.com/post-type-c/post-title/
```

etc.

The query string is set to load different single-post templates, this way I can make a micro site within my excisting wordpress website. However I want to use my other domainname for this microsite, therefore my question.

**UPDATE**

If I put these lines in my .htaccess in the root of domain-b:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain-a\.com$ [NC]
Rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^template=custom$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-b.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

the redirection actually works, however I run into 2 problems:

1) The correct template isn't loaded because the rewrite rule has allready taken off the query string before the function can detect it.
2) http://www.domain-b.com changes back to www.domain-a.com because of the other rewrite rules.

So I think I have to find the solution for problem 1 within my wordpress function instead of .htaccess. Let me explain my situation better:

My main domain with webspace is registered on **domain-b**. My wordpress website is installed in the folder **blog**. I'm using **domain-a** as wordpress url, so **domain-b.com/blog/** redirects to **domain-a**.
That's working fine, but I want to make an exception on these wordpress rewriting rules if the query string is set to **template=custom** like above. In my .htaccess file in the root of the folder **blog** I have the following rules (generated by wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the function I use to load the different single-post template files:

```
// Add Query var
add_filter('query_vars', 'template_query_vars');
function template_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'template';
    return $query_vars;
}

// Switch template according to query parameter
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'sjc_template' );
function sjc_template(){
    global $wp_query;
    if( $wp_query->get( 'template' ) ):
        global $post;
        $posttype = get_post_type($post->ID);
        include( get_template_directory() . '/single-'. $posttype .'-custom.php' );
        exit();
    endif;
}
```

So I tried putting the rewrite rule in there, but that's not working (yet):

```
// Set up the rewrite
add_action( 'init', 'template_setup_rewrites' );
function template_setup_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^/custom/?', '^/?template=custom', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}
```

For problem 2 I somehow have to make an exception on the rewrite rules generated by Wordpress in order to keep domain-a...

Sorry if it's all a bit vague, but it's complicated to explain.
ANY help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if on www.domain-a.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$ [NC]
#and qs contains template=custom
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^template=custom$ [NC]
#redirect any request to domain-b
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-b.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

The only major change was changing the `^$`, which would only match the home page to `^` which will match any request

**Edit** in response to comments

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On 

#if the blog is only supposed to operate on domain-a, restrict it with thie condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^template=custom$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-b.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes this works! However I run into 2 problems:
1) The url rewriting is executed before the correct template is loaded in my functions.php
2) domain-b changes back to domain-a because of other redirection rules.

This is my .htaccess in the root of my domain B:
`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-a\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^template=custom$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-b.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]`

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Wordpress is installed in the folder **blog** and uses domain-a as **Site Address**. So somehow wordpress shouldn't rewrite domain-b back to domain-a if the query string is set...

Comment: @Twansparant For #1, the template parameter is only used to do the redirect, but is not passed through, so not sure how it is used to load the template. For #2, I don't see anything that would cause a redirect back to domain-a. However, Wordpress may redirect it, so I will add a condition to only apply that rule to domain a...

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try as soon as I'm behind my computer again! As for the template loading; this is done with a function in wordpess, I will paste it here when I'm home!